# jVectorMap - How to show region label and not only select region with external link

Tags: jvectormap

I need to show a HTML label when I select a region from external link. 
I can select region using this: `map.setSelectedRegions([region])` but this doesn't show region label.

Anyone could help me with this? Could I generate this label with HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    onRegionClick:function(event, code, region){
                          switch(code){
                            case"your_state":
                                    window.location.replace("http://your_link_address/");
                            break;
                            case"your_state":
                                    window.location.replace("http://your_link_address/");
                            break;  }
                          }
```

Change "your_state" to your state/region. Change "your_link_address" to your address.